After patching my output to 'mock_stdout' using mock tests and using a 'print' statement, why does it not print the output?
I am trying to run unittests for a particular function and I am trying to use mock tests in python. However, it does work as expected.
The 'print' statements my self.sm.do() function are executed and I get the desired output in the console.
But when I do the same by patching it to mock_stdout and then running print(mock_stdout), I get no outputs.
How do I fix this?
import io
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from stack_machine import StackMachine, SMState 


class TestStackMachine(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        
        self.sm = StackMachine()
        
    def test_instance(self):
        """ Essential: Test class instantiation """
        sm = StackMachine()
        self.assertIsInstance(self.sm, StackMachine)

    @patch('sys.stdout', new_callable=io.StringIO)
    def test_with_patch(self, mock_stdout):
        inp_list = [(0,0,0,0,0,1), #push 1
                    (0,0,1,0,1,0), #push 10
                    (0,0,1,0,0,1), #push 9
                    (0,0,0,1,1,1), #push 7
                    (0,0,1,0,0,0), #push 8
                    (0,0,1,1,1,1)] #push 15
        
        out_exp = (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1) #15
        len_exp = 6
        
        for elem in inp_list:
            self.sm.do(elem)

        
        self.assertEqual(self.sm.top(), out_exp)
        self.assertEqual(len(self.sm.stack), len_exp)        
        print(mock_stdout.getvalue())
        #I get no outputs here

    def test_without_patch(self):
        inp_list = [(0,0,0,0,0,1), #push 1
                    (0,0,1,0,1,0), #push 10
                    (0,0,1,0,0,1), #push 9
                    (0,0,0,1,1,1), #push 7
                    (0,0,1,0,0,0), #push 8
                    (0,0,1,1,1,1)] #push 15
        
        out_exp = (0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1) #15
        len_exp = 6
        
        for elem in inp_list:
            self.sm.do(elem)

        
        self.assertEqual(self.sm.top(), out_exp)
        #print(mock_stdout.getvalue())
        self.assertEqual(len(self.sm.stack), len_exp)
        #my print statements from the called function are executed here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()


I have tried to set buffer = False, but it still does not work

What is stack_machine? Is the issue present without it? If yes, remove it from your example for a [mcve]. If no, the issue has to do with what that package does. Do you see the missing prints in your terminal? E.g. the package could be printing from C code.
